# How to know current setting for guicursor shape on Gvim?

Tags: gvim, cursor

I know how to change cursor's shape when using `Gvim`:

```
set guicursor=**options_here**
```

The problem is, it seems like `guicursor` cannot be echoed as far as I know, even though setting it as above works:

```
echo guicursor " receive a undefined variable guicursor
```

So how can I know the current default(?) setting of the cursor shape in `gvim`?
I'm using the version 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either

```
set guicursor?
```

or

```
echo &guicursor
```

See `:h E518` for `set {option}?` and I couldn't find help topic about accessing options in vimscript `&option`. There is `:h let-&` where set option to expression is described.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I tried to look into `&option` myself but didn't find much as you mentioned too. Although I do recall I already knew about using `set something?` but forgot to try it it seems...